# Configure "Done" button for multiple picker views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a scene in which I want to use picker views to get the input for multiple text boxes. I want each picker view to have a toolbar with a "Done" button that dismisses the picker view. So far I have:

```
//toolbar with "Done" button for picker views
UIToolbar *pickerToolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
[pickerToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(doneWithPicker:)];
pickerToolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

//set up picker views
_pickerOne = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
_pickerOne.dataSource = self;
_pickerOne.delegate = self;
self.textFieldOne.inputView = self.pickerOne;
self.textFieldOne.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar;
```

What I need is some way for the doneWithPicker method to figure out which text field is currently being edited and call resignFirstResponder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the text field delegate to identify which field is active. (Make sure to set yourself up as the delegate)

```
@implementation WhateverViewController
{
    UITextField *activeTextField;
}

...

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeTextField = textField;
}
```

Then, in the method that is called when your done button is tapped:

```
[activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
```